# Why is my 6 day old newborn not pooping everyday

Tags: newborn

My 6 day old newborn has not had a bowel movement in almost 2 days. Should I be worried?
She is strictly breastfed.

Comment: If you're concerned, ask your doctor. [Another site](http://www.circleofmoms.com/breastfeeding-moms/my-breastfed-baby-has-only-pooped-one-time-in-7-days-help-377880) seems to have multiple instances as "not to worry" but as every circumstance is different, you may want to make sure your baby is not otherwise uncomfortable.

Comment: A couple of questions before answering: Did she pass meconium (the first blackish stool) within her first 24 hours? Is her bilirubin normal (some newborns have jaundice).

Comment: Your pediatrician expecting you new parents to call. Do it!

Answer (score 7):

Strictly breastfed babies may have from 10 diapers with stool a day, to one diaper with stool every seven to ten days. Breast milk can be so perfectly suited to the newborn that the newborn is able to absorb absolutely everything in the milk, and the only waste is liquid :)

The important thing is that the newborn is urinating frequently, and has many wet diapers every day.

Also, newborns that poop seldom may be uneasy up to a few days before pooping.

Additionally, if the newborn is fed formula milk, there should be a diaper with stool every day.

Source: [Danish health authorities information on newborns](https://www.sundhed.dk/borger/sygdomme-a-aa/boern/om-boern/det-nyfoedte-barn/nyfoedt-barn-tjekliste/) (In Danish)

Comment: The only caveats I would like to add to this is that if the baby appears uncomfortable, don't wait to have her seen, or to assist her in having a bowel movement (another question entirely), and, in the US, 10 days is the cut-off at which we would have the baby seen by a specialist (in other words, 10 days between bowel movements is concerning.) If the baby had problems passing her meconium, it would be sooner than 10 days.